# How can I test/verify if users are tracked across subdomains n Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have my UA setup across three sites www.aerserv.com, platform.aerserv.com, and support.aerserv.com. I want to be sure I'm tracking users across the domains properly so the analytics don't see each visit from one user as a "new user".

Is there a way to verify that I've setup my tracking correctly and Google isn't mis counting visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdomain tracking is done out of the box in GA, and the only thing you need to make sure is that the cookie domain setting is set to 'auto', and that the referral exclusion list includes the main domain. Once you have those set, and if all pages across all applicable subdomains are tagged, then you should not have any issues. If you need to check, then you can look at the client ID (cid) for each pageview hit from one subdomain to the next. The client ID should be the same.

Comment: As nyuen says GA does it automatically. If you really want to verify it, you can for example visit main domain and type in webdev console something like: ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId'); (codes can vary depands how you implement GA) this should return your clientID seted by ga object. Then visit any subdomain and type this code again and just compare id.

Comment: Thanks!! I was able to confirm the CID was the same across my domain and sub domains using the command you gave me for console!